# How to deploy app for a lower target than it was written for? iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, deployment

I originally wrote an app for iOS 9.3, later when the iOS 10 came I changed the build for to 10 and updated old functions to their newer versions. The final release was with 9.3 deployment target to provide the app also for users that haven't upgraded yet. Than unreasonable crashes started to occur while using the app on 9.3 iOS devices. I found out that the problem was within the updated methods to newer iOS 10 form. How to release the app for lower deployment target, while code fits the newest forms? Do I need to change those methods back to iOS 9.3 version? Will they be supported 100% on iOS 10 devices?

Comment: In some cases you may need to test for specific versions and handle each differently; Generally if you set your target to 9.3, Xcode will warn you about incompatibilities.  Your question is too broad, however, and you need to give specific details about specific errors and/or crashes including relevant code

Comment: In this case the problem occurs for ex. in -[UIApplication openURL:options:completionHandler:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fee9070bcd0 which is method from iOS 10 when I run it on 9.3 simulator

Comment: So in that case you can either continue to use the deprecated `openURL` function or you can use `if #available` to include both iOS 9 and iOS 10 code

Comment: How can I find the rest of deprecated functions I have changed during the development without using the actual iOS 9 device?

Comment: You can add the ios9 simulator and test on that. Personally, I am not converting my code to Swift 3 and iOS 10 until I am ready to abandon earlier versions. Coexistence is too painful

Comment: Thank you for your advices Paulw11 hope I will solve it soon